# Labeling the answers by numbers

Tags: support, sorting

I am kindly asking:

Can it be manageable by the Masters of the site to label the answers coming for a problem  by a number showing that which answer is came earlier and which one is later. However, I have seen that it is being done by indicating the time the answer came. This is an idea for M.SE. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uh, why? We can already sort the answer by time. (Look at a question with multiple answers, for example [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) ; right before the beginning of the answers section on the right you have three tabs: click on "Oldest"

[image]

and the answers will be sorted in chronological order.) Would that not be enough?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that, Willie. ;-)